# What is the Catholic church's view on credo-baptist?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, doctrine

I would like to know if Catholic church considers credo-baptism a heresy? And also what exactly there stance is on it?

Comment: Please define "credo-baptism" in your question.  For addedness, include its opposite paedo-baptism.

Comment: I agree with @SLM; if @NeilMeyer is asking whether the Church allows parents the option of waiting for the child to reach the age of reason before baptising them, then she does; if he is asking whether a Catholic is allowed to hold that infant baptism is invalid or otherwise not preferable, then they may not.